# What kind of sources are acceptable to demonstrate the "existence" of a claim made on a History Chanel type program?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, notability

If I want to request input on a claim made on a television program for entertainment purposes rather than from a scientific source. For example, Ancient Aliens, Curse of Oak Island, etc., what kind of source is considered acceptable to demonstrate that the claim exists?

For example, would the season and episode number be considered where the claim appeared acceptable, or would I need to use a source external to the program that discusses its content?

In the latter's case, would a popular thread on a discussion forum be acceptable?

This is to prove that a claim has been made or that a question has been asked, not to demonstrate any form of a scientific basis for it.

Answer (score 5):

We ask for references to the claim in questions for a number of reasons:

- So we can see that it is a widely heard claim. We don't want to waste our time  reading/answering/editing/voting on spurious claims invented by some inebriated person in a bar. If you know the name of the show, a reference to IMDB or Wikipedia would be fine for that.
- So we can see that it is an accurate version of the claim. People sometimes describe claims that never appear in the source, and we end up tackling a strawman. Include a transcription of the claim (and some of the context). If you can link to a YouTube version *as well* that would be best.
- So we can research the full context - especially, looking for unusual definitions and misunderstood irony. Again, a link to a video is best for this, but if that isn't available, that's fine. It might make it less likely to get an answer though.

Comment: I would emphasize that if the source is unavailable publicly, you really should provide an exact quote and make clear that you're quoting the show at this point. There are just too many ways paraphrasing the claim can go wrong, the odds that the question will be received well are much better if you can add a clearly marked exact quote from the show.

Comment: @Oddthinking, I think that you may have misunderstood the question. I'm not asking why a source is required, I'm asking about the type of source that is required. I will edit my question to be more specific.

Comment: @Mad Scientist, surely a television program is publlic?

Comment: @AaarghZombies To be more precise, easily accessible from a link for everyone. A television program is usually not available to everyone in every country. And even then for videos we usually like a transcript of the relevant part so that not everyone has to watch the video.

Comment: @AaarghZombies: I don't think I misunderstood. I went back to the reasons *why* a source is required to justify what we expect. The last sentence of each bullet points should be the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @Oddthinking, I didn't ask why sources were required, I asked if a made for entertainment TV program or a discussion thread was considered appropriate to confirm the existence of a claim being made. Which you didn't answer. Please do not put commentary in your answer, it derails things.

Comment: @Mad Scientist, wouldn't that essential rule out all of the live whitehouse press briefings over covid and vaccine safety as they're us only and not archived in full? Or any program not currently airing in the US? But, if I can put up a youtube clip to it, then it's 100 percent OK to use that as a source? What about forum threads such as urban legend discussions?

Comment: @AaarghZombies: *Shrug* It isn't commentary, it is a justification. If I, as a mod, gave an answer to that question without any justification, it would be an Appeal to Authority fallacy. If a claim is in a TV program, then it can be used as long as you do the things I said (reference to IMDB, transcribe claim and context, and link to online video if you can) for the reasons I gave.